# How to add a new profile entry to Firefox's profiles.ini using a script?

Tags: text-processing, sed, scripting, firefox

Firefox uses a text file named `~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini` to hold a list of profiles. The entries look similar to this:

```
[Profile0]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=default
Default=1

...

[Profile8]
Name=guest
IsRelative=1
Path=guest
```

I need to add a new entry to `profiles.ini` using a bash script. The catch is that the profiles need to be numbered sequentially and I do not know in advance how many profiles each user has. In the above example, I would need to add [Profile9]. If instead, I add [Profile8] or [Profile10] or any other number, it will not work correctly.

How can my script figure out which is the highest profile number currently in use, then increment that and append a new profile to `profiles.ini`?

I have gotten as far as something like this used in a `for-loop`, but I don't know how to get `$NewNumber`.

```
echo "[Profile$NewNumber]
Name=NewProfile
IsRelative=1
Path=NewPath" >> /home/$myuser/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps use awk to extract the "[Profile]" lines then process away the "[Profile ... ]" bits, then sort the results numerically, keeping only the last (highest) one:

```
highest=$(awk '/^\[Profile[0-9]+\]$/ { s=substr($0, 9); sub("]","", s); print s}' < /home/$myuser/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini |sort -n | tail -1)
highest=$((highest + 1))
printf "[Profile%d]
Name=NewProfile
IsRelative=1
Path=NewPath" "$highest" >> /home/$myuser/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini
```

Answer (score 3):

The easy way:

```
/usr/bin/firefox -CreateProfile profileName
```

It will maintain the profiles in the `profiles.ini` file and create a new one (`profileName` in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Why not an all `awk` approach?

```
awk '
/Profile[0-9]+/ {PRNR = $0
                 gsub (/[^0-9]/, "", PRNR)
                }
1
END             {print ""
                 print "[Profile" ++PRNR "]"
                 print "Name=NewProfile"
                 print "IsRelative=1"
                 print "Path=NewPath >> /home/$myuser/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini"
                }
' profiles.ini
```

Comment: I like this approach. It is returning the correct profile number. However, running it is outputting the new profile to stdout rather than appending it to /home/$myuser/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini. I assume also that the final `profiles.ini` refers to the input file, right?

Comment: Redirect `stdout` to a temp file, and then overwrite the original. And yes, `profile.ini` is the original input file.

Comment: Redirecting stdout does work, but that last bit, `>> /home/$myuser/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini`, ends up in the output file. Somehow, the `>>` isn't doing it's intended job. I could delete it and redirect stdout myself, but that does not seem to be what you intended in your answer. If that's resolved, I could accept your answer because I do like the all-awk approach.

Comment: Don't append to the original. `awk ... >/tmp/TMP$$; mv /tmp/TMP$$ original_file` will install the new, extended `.ini` file --- Ohh, got you. remove that `>> /home.../profile.ini` from the `awk` script...